# Why does `++a++` not compile in C++ but `(++a)++` does?

Tags: java, c++, lvalue, rvalue

What the title says. For C++, `(++a)++` does compile. Strangely enough, though, `++(a++)` does not:

```
int main() {
    int a = 0;
    ++a++; // does not compile
    (++a)++; // does compile
    ++(a++); // does not compile
}
```

But in Java, it does not for all three:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        ++a++; // does not compile
        (++a)++; // does not compile
        ++(a++); // does not compile
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why C++ compiles this but not in Java?

Comment: What C++ compiler? And in what sense do you think `a++` is a `void` statement?

Comment: @FredLarson I used the `C++11` compiler on ideone.com, but I would think it is allowable on any C++ compiler. I think it is a `void` statement because it is equivalent (functionally) to: `a = a+1;` which doesn't give an actual value.

Comment: `"...a parser using only one-token lookahead and no semantic analysis during the parse would not be able to tell, when ++ is the lookahead token, whether (p) should be considered a Primary expression or left alone for later consideration as part of a CastExpression."`

Comment: @Ryan: You're incorrect about that. `a++` returns the value of `a` before the increment.

Comment: @FredLarson Ok yeah I see what you mean. But then why is `++(a++)` not compile-able then, since `a++` returns the value of `a` before the increment?

Comment: It is time for these operators to be deprecated anyway... IMO its much better to write out calculations without '++' or '--' as the performance gain is minimal (especially with modern compilers / code optimizers) and doesn't validate making the code harder to read

Comment: Of course you can always do `++ ++a` if you do not need 'a-1`  afterwards.

Comment: @bmargulies that can not be a duplicate since it only covers C++ and the question is clearly not solely about C++. Conceptually they are similar issue but the answers are different for Java than in C++ which is actually the point of the question.

Comment: @ControlAltDel imagine how much code would have to be changed in order to deprecate those operators, pretty much any C and C++ code out there uses those operators.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None of the examples work in Java because both postfix and prefix increment operations return *values* not *variables* we can see this by going to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) section on [Postfix Increment Operator ++](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) for an example and it says:

> The result of the postfix increment expression is not a variable, but a value.

The JLS section for [Prefix Increment Operator ++](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1) says the same thing.

This would be like trying to increment a literal value (*[see it live](http://rextester.com/SCDT67524)*):

```
2++ ;
++3 ;
```

which gives the following error:

```
required: variable
found:    value
```

Which is the same error we receive for your examples.

In C++ prefix increment returns an lvalue but postfix increment returns an prvalue and both prefix and postfix increment in C++ require an lvalue. So your first and third C++ example:

```
++a++;
++(a++)
```

fails because you are attempting to apply prefix increment to a prvalue. While the second C++ example:

```
(++a)++;
```

is okay because prefix increment returns an lvalue.

For reference the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) in section `5.2` *Postfix expressions* says:

> The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value of its operand [...] The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue

and:

> The result is a prvalue

and section `5.3` *Unary expressions* says:

> The operand of prefix ++ is modified [...] The
>   operand shall be a modifiable lvalue

and:

> The result is the updated operand; it is an lvalue